# Rails Devise: Redirect user to current page after signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

If I access http://example.com, I am first taken to the login page and after successful login, to the home page.
If I access http://example.com/myusers, after successful login, I want to be redirected to the current page and not the home page.

After reading a few online posts, I understood that in my application_controller.rb I can manipulate the after_sign_in_path_for method. I tested this by adding a specific url to this method and I always get redirected to that url after a successful login.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     "http://example.com/users"    
end
```

How can I make this method capture the URL that the user requested before signing in and redirect the user accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise comes with something like this out-of-the-box. As part of the failure scenario it stores the last request. This "How-to" should help you with the solution. Note that you need to call this method in your before_filter of the controller(s):

```
before_filter: authenticate_user!
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#a-simpler-solution

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Didn't know devise did this already. Awesome!

Comment: Their "How-To"-Section is actually pretty good. Lots of great stuff and examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the requested URL in a session variable.

```
session[:return_to] = request.original_url
```

You can set the session variable inside of an `before_action :authorize` method in your application controller, this may make sense somewhere else depending on your authorization strategy.

```
def authorize
  if current_user_authorized?
    # Authorized...
  else
    # Record the requested page URL and redirect to the login page.
    session[:return_to] = request.original_url
    redirect_to login_url, error: "Not authorized."
  end
end
```

To use it you can write:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:return_to] || root_url
end
```